# how to add a loading gif image to my web page

Tags: php, javascript

how can i add a loading gif image when every time i try to load a page,i have an admin page with links on it ,i  want when i click on a link before the page loads it should show the gif image,i added some javascript code on the header tag and in the body tag i added this code

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

the admin page looks like this

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function preloader(){
            document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
        }//preloader
        window.onload = preloader;
</script>
        <title>profile- Admin panel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="loading"></div>    
<?php include 'includes/connect.php'; ?>
<?php include 'title_bar.php'; ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loading.css">

<h3>admin panel system</h3>
<p> you are logged in as <b><?php echo $username?></b> [<?php echo $level_name;?>]</p>
<?php
if($user_level != 1){
 header('location : profile.php');

}

?>

<p>
 <ul class="dash">                          
            <li>
            <a href="#" title="Report" class="tip" data-placement="bottom" >
            <img src="images/icons/report.png" alt="" />
            <span>Report</span>
            </a>
            </li>

             <li>
            <a href="view.php" title="Customers" class="tip" data-placement="bottom" >
            <img src="images/icons/customers.png" alt="" />

            <span>Customers</span>
            </a>
            </li>
            </ul>

</p>
<p>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['type']) && !empty($_GET['type'])){
?>
<table>
<tr><td width='150px'> Users</td><td>Options</td></tr>
<?php
 $list_query = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, type FROM users");
 while($run_list = mysql_fetch_array($list_query)){
  $u_id = $run_list['id'];
  $u_username = $run_list['username'];
  $u_type = $run_list['type'];
 ?>
 <tr><td><?php echo $u_username?></td><td>
 <?php
 if($u_type == 'a'){
     echo "<a href='option.php?u_id=$u_id&type=$u_type'>Deactivate</a>";

} else{

    echo "<a href='option.php?u_id=$u_id&type=$u_type'>activate</a>";
}


 ?>

 </td></tr>
 <?php
 }
?>
</table> 
<?php

} else{

   echo "Select Options Above";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

this is what i have in the loading.css

```
div#content {
    display: none;
    }

div#loading {             
    top: 200 px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 160px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url('../images/loading (1).gif') no-repeat;
    cursor: wait;                
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can have a loader between page redirection...I know that you can have it for every ajax call for example which is a good idea because when you fetch data from the server you don't want to have any user interactions...

Comment: In your `style` did you notice the space `../images/loading (1).gif` in the name of the image set as background url of that `<div>` ?

Comment: Maybe try and use `window.onbeforeunload` and load the animated gif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a content div. You need to wrap everything aside from the loader in a div with the id "content".

```
<div id="content">
<h3>admin panel system</h3>
    ...
</div>
</body>
```

Aside from that, on a simple page the load event will fire very quickly. Unless there are a lot of images on the page the user will probably only see a flicker. If you really want them to see the page then you can add a half second delay to your preload function.

```
function preloader(){
    setTimeout(function(){    
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
    }, 500);
}//preloader
```

You can also experiment with reversing the preload (hide content, show loading again) in the onunload function for when they change pages. If your pages take a while to process (slow database calls etc) you can look into flushing the page up to the end of the loading div before the processing happens.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Ultimately though, I'd suggest the loader is more trouble than it's worth and will only annoy the user. Loaders often fine with ajax when you have complete control of the request cycle but in this case I'm not sure. Experiment, see what works best. Good luck.